# Click the download button on the second tab that's opened after pressing view PDF button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The below code will click the view PDF button on a fedex tracking number, it will populate a second tab.
I'm having issues downloading this page as a PDF, or printing it as a PDF, as Ctrl+P or Ctrl+S do not work.

I believe my only option is to click the download button.. The issue is that the download button is nested in shadow-doms.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pyautogui
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from seleniumbase import Driver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Helper for getting the shadow root of a shadow host
def getShadowRoot(host):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", host)
    return shadow_root



wait = time.sleep(2)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Add the driver options
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, version_main=122)
driver.get('https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?trknbr=123456789012&trkqual=2460234000~123456789012~FX')
windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
driver.maximize_window()



# Select Obtain proof button
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="obtain-proof-link-id"]'))).click()

# Select View POD button
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="fdx-c-button fdx-c-button--primary fdx-c-button--responsive fdx-u-pt--4 fdx-u-pb--4"]').click()
wait
wait

# Click the Download Button
```

[image]