# Switch to second tab with Selenium Chrome - About:Blank

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

What's the correct way to switch to a second tab?

Right now I click a link on a website, which opens another window but the tab is about:blank.

I'm trying to do something on this page but Selenium is still on the default content, how can I change to the next handle?

I've tried to follow documentation here but couldn't figure it out myself, https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows

[image]

This is what I have, but this is only detecting one tab being open, even though the image below shows two.

I am receiving an error on line 37,

> wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
> ^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'until'

```
from seleniumbase import Driver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = 'https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?trknbr=123456789012&trkqual=2460234000~123456789012~FX'
driver = Driver(uc=True, external_pdf = True)
driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()

# Setup wait for later
wait = time.sleep(2)

# Select Obtain proof button
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="obtain-proof-link-id"]'))).click()
wait

# Select View PDF button
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="fdx-c-button fdx-c-button--primary fdx-c-button--responsive fdx-u-pt--4 fdx-u-pb--4"]'))).click()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\\Users\\User1\\Downloads\\BPAAS",
  "download.prompt_for_download": True,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})


WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

# Wait for new window to open and switch to it
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
    if window_handle != original_window:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break

print(driver.current_url)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: looks like you're doing things correctly, but the code you posted is a little odd.  Can you include the actual code you are trying?  The code, as is, will not even create a webdriver or click a link.

Comment: Sorry about that, code is updated.

Comment: you sure that's the actual code?  I see some issues here... one is this line: wait = time.sleep(2)... later on you use wait.until(...)  which shouldn't work.  You're also setting an options object but not using... and doing that after the driver has been created.  You've also defined original_window and all_window_handles early on without a reason to... (remove those)  Otherwise, the code looks fine.... after that loop the driver should be in the 2nd window/tab.

Comment: Cleaned up again, sorry, i'm really just trying anything I can so it is a little messy.  You can try and run it yourself, it opens the new tab by clicking the link, but hangs and doesn't switch to the new tab.

Comment: you should also try/catch your driver calls to see if exceptions are thrown and what they are... that should help.  I'm not real sure what the handle will be for about:blank, or if there will be a handle.  (they are a bit different for local/remote domains, methinks... not sure what about: blank would be regarding domain)

Comment: the other issue would be if there is actually a DOM in the new tab.  If there is not, Selenium won't be able to do anything with it.  Right-click on the tab and choose, "Inspect" to see if there's markup there.  If there is no markup the only thing you can do in that tab is use another get() or navigate() method.

Comment: you should use WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2)) that will also help... (try/catch to be sure a timeout is not thrown...)

Comment: That works, It will wait, and it recognizes two windows are open, but it still won't switch focus. I can print out the window ID's.

Comment: The point browsermator is making is that the code you have posted *will not run* as is. I just tried it. There are incomplete and incorrect lines of code in there that will throw immediately. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work. The problem is that you're opening a tab that contains a PDF but Selenium can't see inside that PDF because it's not a webpage so you're going to have to get another library if you want to do something with the PDF.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?trknbr=123456789012&trkqual=2460234000~123456789012~FX'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Click Obtain proof link
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "obtain-proof-link-id"))).click()

# Click View PDF button
original_window = driver.current_window_handle
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()=' View PDF ']"))).click()

# Wait for new window to open and switch to it
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
    if window_handle != original_window:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break

# we're now in the new tab, do stuff
```

Comment: Jeff, i've updated my code above also using a suggestion from browsermator. I have to use UC due to bot detection on the fedex site, and i'm using Seleniumbase to change the download button to the middle of the re-directed page to avoid having to select through shadow-doms.

Comment: If the new tab is really just a PDF file, I believe there's a preference you can set in ChromeOptions that would force a download instead of using its internal viewer.

Comment: My view here, I'm able to successfully navigate to the PDF page, but, there's an "Open" button, that I need to click, which will download it to a set directory. I need to switch to the correct tab because selenium still views the original tracking page as the default tab.  If I don't use the Experimental_Options in my code above, then I have to click the download button which is hosted through 4 shadow-roots which I can't figure out how to code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78228454/click-the-download-button-on-the-second-tab-thats-opened-after-pressing-view-pd

Which I posted here, but I could not figure that out :(

Answer (score 1):

this is a real hacky way to accomplish the goal, but I was able to use pyautogui to focus on the chrome window, press tab, and enter. It's not the correct way to do it, but with some error handling you can avoid mistakes or going further.

Adding this to the bottom of the code in the first post will download a file to a directory.

```
# hacky way to download the pdf
def find_chrome_window():
    # Find the active Chrome window
    chrome_windows = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Google Chrome')
    if chrome_windows:
        return chrome_windows[0]
    else:
        return None

def press_tab_and_enter():
    chrome_window = find_chrome_window()
    if chrome_window:
        # Activate Chrome window
        chrome_window.activate()

        # Simulate pressing Tab and Enter keys
        pyautogui.press('tab')
        time.sleep(0.5)  # Add a small delay between Tab and Enter
        pyautogui.press('enter')
    else:
        print("Chrome window not found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    press_tab_and_enter()
```